# IIS URL Rewrite to remove WWW for a subdomain

Tags: url, url-rewriting

I am trying to remove the www from www.kelli.mydomain.com. Where Kelli could be anything (*). We are using AWS ELB and have our SSL on the ELB. but when the string gets to the ELB we get SSL errors because of the subdomain(www)

```
<rule name="Remove WWW for mygc.com" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^(.*)$" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.*.mygc.com)$" />
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:2}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

I am no IIS expert but need help. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, here is the web config section:<rule name="Remove WWW for mygc.com" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">11:44:03 AM
<match url="^(.*)$" />11:44:03 AM
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">11:44:03 AM
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.*.mygc.com)$" />11:44:03 AM
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" />11:44:03 AM
</conditions>11:44:03 AM
<action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:2}" appendQueryString="true" />11:44:03 AM
</rule>

Answer (score 0):

The following rule works on the domain mygc.com stripping off all www from subdomains.  {R:0} is the content after the / in the URL, {C:1} is the subdomain from the conditional

```
<rule name="Remove WWW for mygc.com" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^(.*)$" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.(.*)\.mygc\.com$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:1}.mygc.com/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

This can be done more generally without hardcoding the domain

```
<rule name="Remove WWW from subdomains" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^(.*)$" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:1}.{C:2}.{C:3}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```